# Classify file extension and applying logic

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Need to execute logic depending on the file extension.

Input: `$FileName = "ABC.tar.gz.manifest" or "ABC.tar.gz" or "ABC.zip"`

```
$EXTZ = ".zip"
$EXTGZ = "tar.gz"
$EXT = $FileName -match "$EXTZ"

$EXT
if ($EXT = 'True') {
    Write-Host "$EXTZ"
} elseif ($EXT = 'False') {
   Write-Host "$EXTGZ"
}
```

But the problem is some files are having the double extension.
How we can solve this?

If the extension is `.zip` need to print "ABC".

If the file extension is `.tar.gz` or `.tar.gz.manifest` need to print "XYZ".

Comment: the `fileinfo` object that you get from `Get-Item` or `Get-ChildItem` has a `.Extension` property - so use that. [*grin*]

Comment: I am new to powershell, Can you please help me on this with example.

Comment: use `Get-Item` to read a file object to a $Var, then use `$Var | Select-Object -Property *` to show all the props of that object. you will see a _bunch_ of properties - one of them will be `.Extension` and it will have the very last `.Whatever` in it. for example, `MyNiftyFile.txt.Log` will have `.Log` in it. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey The last not good for him because he will need to check twice: `.manifest` and `.gz`

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk - thank you for catching that. [*grin*] i somehow missed that detail ... [*blush*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the `$fileInfo` contains the extension (you have a problem in the `if`, in PowerShell you can't do `=`, you do `-eq`):

```
$Filename = "ABC.tar.gz.manifest"
$EXTGZ = "tar.gz"
$EXT = $Filename.Contains($EXTGZ)
if($EXT -eq $true)
{
   # Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a Regular Expression and a `switch` instead of multiple if commands

```
## Q:\Test\2019\05\27\SO_56322763.ps1

foreach ($FileName in ("ABC.tar.gz.manifest","ABC.tar.gz","ABC.zip","foo.bar")){
    "`$FileName is: {0}" -f $FileName

    switch -regex ($FileName){
        "\.tar\.gz(\.manifest)?$" {"XYZ";Break}
        "\.zip$"                  {"ABC";Break}
        default                   {"anything"}
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2019\05\27\SO_56322763.ps1
$FileName is: ABC.tar.gz.manifest
XYZ
$FileName is: ABC.tar.gz
XYZ
$FileName is: ABC.zip
ABC
$FileName is: foo.bar
anything
```