# Need to trim the extension for double extension filename

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have some files with the names as below,

Input could be one of the below,

> ABC.sample.tar.gz
>
> XYZ.sample.tar.gz.Manifest
>
> 123.sample.zip

i have couple of requirements

1. Need to trim off the extension totally and store the filename without extension into a variable.

> Sample output: $filename=ABC.sample or XYZ.sample or 123.sample

2. Need to trim only ".manifest" if it exists and stores into another variable.

Code:

```
$SURL = "ABC.sample.tar.gz.manifest"
$UDRname = [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($SURL)
$UDRname
```

Output: `ABC.sample.tar.gz`

**Expectation:**

1. Actual file extensions have to removed like below

> $filename=ABC.sample
>
> $filename=XYZ.sample
>
> $filename=123.sample

2. If the file name is having .manifest in the filename.
   It has to trimmed away.

> $trimed = XYZ.sample.tar.gz

Comment: Can you add some code extracts of work you've completed on this issue already?

Comment: Why is `.sample` not considered an extension in your world? What are the rules?

Comment: File name syntax could be like below,
Username_Date.tar.gz.manifest 
where username may have some dots in it

Comment: If the list of extensions you encounter is constant, you can use `-replace` (`"abc.sample.tar.gz" -replace "(\.tar\.gz)|(\.zip)$", ""`). Things are more annoying if they're not, as the problem becomes inherently ambiguous (is (`jimmy.tar.gz` the user named `jimmy` or the user named `jimmy.tar` with a `.gz` extension?)

Comment: You ***did*** read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56324596/6811411) to your other question referring to [regex] and `switch`?

Comment: @lotpings yes, but your answer is for all possible inputs.for my scenario only one input will be provided at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem you will hit is with the `[IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($SURL)` which does not support the concept of multiple extensions.

By adding a special consideration for multiple dot extensions,
here's something that should work for you.

Add any other multiple extensions (excluding the manifest one) in the `$DoubleExtensions` to cover other cases you might have.

Consider the following:

```
Function Get-FileInfos($FullName) {
    $DoubleExtensions = @('.tar.gz')
    $Manifestext = '.manifest'
    $IsManifest = $FullName.EndsWith($Manifestext)
    $Extension, $TrimmedName = $null    
    $NameToProcess = $FullName

    # Process manifest extention
    if ($IsManifest) {
        $TrimmedName = [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($FullName)
        $NameToProcess = $TrimmedName
    }

    # Process double extensions
    Foreach ($Ext in $DoubleExtensions) {
        if ($NameToProcess.EndsWith($Ext)) {
            if ($IsManifest -eq $false) {
                $Extension = $Ext
                $ShortName = $NameToProcess.Substring(0, $NameToProcess.Length - $ext.Length)
            }
            else {
                $Extension = $Ext
                $ShortName = $NameToProcess
            }
            break 
        }
    }

    # Process normal extensions 
    if ($null -eq $Extension ) {

        if ($IsManifest -eq $false) {
            $Extension = [io.Path]::GetExtension($NameToProcess)
            $ShortName = [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($NameToProcess)
        }
        else {
            $ShortName = $NameToProcess
        }

    }

    # If manifest, extension should be .manifest without original file extension
    if ($IsManifest) { $Extension = $Manifestext }

    return [PSCustomObject]@{
        FullName    = $FullName
        TrimmedName = $TrimmedName
        ShortName   = $ShortName
        Extension   = $Extension
    }
}
```

**Sample test**

```
$TestList = @(
    'ABC.sample.tar.gz.manifest'
    'DEF.sample.tar.gz'
    'GHI.Sample.manifest'
    'JKL.exe'
)

$TestList | foreach { Get-FileInfos -FullName $_ }
```

**Result**
[image: Results]

Comment: How to test this for a single input? like $TestList = "ABC.sample.tar.gz.manifest"